# How to simplify this expression using logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I want to find the value of this expression in as simple way as possible.

$$  \frac{1+ 2\log_3 2}{(1+ \log_3 2)^2}+ \log^2_6 2  $$

I simplified and I am stuck at 
$$ \frac{1+2\log_3 2+2\log_6 2+4\log_3 2×2\log_6 2}{1+4\log_3 2} $$

Comment: Formatting tip use \log for proper spacing also use ^n for raising something to nth power i.e x^2 for $x^2$.

Comment: I simply expanded the denominator and found nothing helpful,it doesn't simplifies. I think I'm not doing it the right way

Comment: See now I have edited.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, as you see you need to write your efforts before asking here, because may some user downvote your question. In this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) you have how translate your logarithms as logarithms to base $e$, that are $\log_e x=\ln x$. Is only grammar. The formula that I am saying is in section  *Change of base*. Was the answer below.  +1 and good luck.

Comment: @user243301  A greatest of the great thanks to you. I'll never forget your guidelines in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that $\log_ab = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$

Then the expression becomes:

$$\frac{1 + 2\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}}{(1+\frac{\log 2}{\log 3})^2} + (\frac{\log 2}{\log 6})^2$$

$$= \frac{1 + 2\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}}{1+2\frac{\log 2}{\log 3} + \frac{\log^2 2}{\log^2 3}} + (\frac{\log 2}{\log 3 + \log 2})^2$$

$$= \frac{\log^23 + 2\log 2\log 3}{\log^23+2\log2\log 3 + \log^2 2} + \frac{\log^2 2}{\log^23 + 2\log2\log3 + \log^22}$$

$$= \frac{\log^23 + 2\log 2\log 3 + \log^22}{\log^23+2\log2\log 3 + \log^2 2}$$

$$=1$$

Comment: I really appreciate your help.